# First time when I open a popup (Mapbox)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, popup, mapbox

I'm trying to create a popup, but first time I do not get the right style. What I can be doing wrong?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

My html.

```
<canvas id='canvas' style="min-width: 600px; margin: -4px"></canvas>
```

My JavaScript code

```
map.on('click', 'region-capa', function (e) {
    if (typeof myChart != 'undefined') {
        myChart.destroy();
    }
    if (e) {
        nombre = e.features[0].properties.SST_NOMBRE;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Mapa/GetEstadisticas/" + parseInt(e.features[0].properties.SST_ID),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response) {
                    grafica(response);
                    new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: true, closeOnClick: true })
                        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                        .setDOMContent(canvas)
                        .addTo(map);
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Example that I got: 
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2707903/35266189-c11f0856-0022-11e8-9a4e-0e8c2a8420a0.JPG

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer.

I've change responsive options to **false** of my Chartjs config